# Have price label appear in the y axis scale with tradingiew and pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Im using pine script with Trading View.  I have a list of y values (prices) in an array.  I want to draw a horizontal line and a label at each y value but to the right of the horizontal line / right of chart.

I do this fine with pinescript with line.new() and label.new(), but i'd like the actual price value to also appear on the y axis like as if i had physically drawn the horizontal line.  I was wondering whether plot() could be used but couldnt see how.

Anyone know how i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that with `line.new()`. You can do it with the `plot()` function but you need to change your chart's settings.

Having those values in an array might be a little bit tricky as you cannot call `plot()` in a local scope.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
plot(low, "Low price")
```

[image]

Comment: yeah - my values are in an array so cant use a for loop which is why im stumped